# What are the exact 18 Mahapuranas?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, bhavishya-purana

What are the names of 18 Mahapuranas?Some resources have **Bhavisya Purana** but do not have **Shiva Purana** in their list, while some have **Shiva Purana** in place of **Bhavisya Purana**. I came across this difference in lot of websites. Please clarify why there is such a difference, why there is such a difference. Thank you.